# SetWindowFont for dialog doesn't work

Tags: winapi

Creating of dialog

```
HWND dialog = CreateDialog(hInst, (LPSTR)"TEMPLATE", hWnd, (DLGPROC)Proc);
```

Creating of font

```
HFONT newFont = CreateFont(72, 0, 0, 0, FW_DONTCARE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, ANSI_CHARSET,
    OUT_TT_PRECIS, CLIP_DEFAULT_PRECIS, DEFAULT_QUALITY,
    DEFAULT_PITCH | FF_DONTCARE, TEXT("Tahoma"));
SetWindowFont(dialog, newFont, true);
DWORD err = GetLastError();
```

err says that there aren't any errors, but the font is still the same(not changed)

I have always tried to set the font from "Proc" dialog function in case of WM_INITDIALOG message

When I set a font by calling a function SendDlgItemMessage with dialog handler and ID of Edit component (for example) in template it works fine. But I haven't such an ID for window or title of the window to try this aproach

How to set a font for a dialog caption/title?

Comment: There is no point to this code.  The font used to display the caption of a window is a user theme setting.

Comment: Windows are not obligated to respond to `WM_SETFONT`; for all we know `DefDlgProc()` could just call `DefWindowProc()` which could just ignore the message entirely. In addition, MSDN says "This message does not return a value. ", so what error could `SetWindowFont()` return? If you want to change the caption font, you have to custom draw the window caption. If you want to change the font of all the controls, you either need to change your dialog template or (if you need to change after the fact) work in a loop changing every single control's font individually.